# Why are we using ...form and not just form?

Tags: javascript

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; 

export default function RegisterForm() { 
  const [form, setForm] = useState({ 
    firstName: 'Luke', 
    lastName: 'Jones', 
    email: 'lukeJones@sculpture.com', 
  }); 

  return ( 
    <> 
      <label> 
        First name: 
        <input 
          value={form.firstName} 
          onChange={e => { 
            setForm({ 
              ...form, 
              firstName: e.target.value 
            }); 
          }} 
        /> 
      </label> 
      <label> 
        Last name: 
        <input 
          value={form.lastName} 
          onChange={e => { 
            setForm({ 
              ...form, 
              lastName: e.target.value 
            }); 
          }} 
        /> 
      </label> 
      <label> 
        Email: 
        <input 
          value={form.email} 
          onChange={e => { 
            setForm({ 
              ...form, 
              email: e.target.value 
            }); 
          }} 
        /> 
      </label> 
      <p> 
        {form.firstName}{' '} 
        {form.lastName}{' '} 
        ({form.email})
      </p> 
    </> 
  ); 
}
```

The code is working differently but I want to know what is happening behind it.

Comment: For your own searching... What you're seeing is called [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The "..." are the javascript spread operator.

Basically, it makes a "copy" of the original object. In the case you show, a copy of the form is being made, then the field is being modified with the new value entered, and it is being saved in the form state.

I recommend you check the official javascript configuration about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax